Split array into sub arrays based on difference between two adjacent elements
Given a sorted array of integers:
let array = [1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 12]

I would like to partition it at the index where difference between two adjacent numbers exceed 2 and create a new sub array, such that I have the following output in the end:
[ [1,3,4], [7,8], [12] ]

What would be an elegant way to achieve this in Swift. Does Combine framework provides a built in operator for this?

FYI - the Combine framework is described as "Customize handling of asynchronous events by combining event-processing operators." so it does not seem to be relevant for your task.

What is elegant is a matter of opinion (off-topic here). As to your second question: why not check the documentation? Can you demonstrate your research efforts?

I don't understand the question. To "partition an array arr" means to means to divide it into two arrays, [a[1],...,a[i]] and [a[i+1],...,a[n-1]], for some index i. You are not doing that. Do you mean you want to end up with three arrays?  What if the array were [2,3]? Were [1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9]? Were [1,2,5,6,9,10,13,14]?

Yes, some implementations use the term “partition” narrowly, as you have, but the OP’s more general use of the term is acceptable. IMHO, the provided example makes the OP’s intent perfectly clear.

You can use chunked(by:) in the Swift Algorithms package
let grouped = array.chunked(by: { $0 + 2 >= $1 }).map(Array.init)


Disclaimer: this solution assumes the example in the question. Substitute force cast with null-checks if your use case may include empty arrays.

The easiest way to achieve grouping of an array is using the reduce function which is useful if we want to transform our array into some different data structure:
let arr = [1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 12]

let result = arr.dropFirst().reduce(into: [[arr.first!]]) {
    if abs($0.last!.last! - $1) >= 3 {
        $0.append([$1])
    } else {
        $0[$0.endIndex - 1].append($1)
    }
}

print(result)

The logic is this:

if the last element of the current result has a difference of 3 or more to the currently iterated element, then start a new sub-array ("if" clause)
otherwise, append the currently iterated element to the last sub-array ("else" clause).

which will print
[[1, 3, 4], [7, 8], [12]]


FYI - this code will crash if the array is empty.

"Given a sorted array of integers" - I think that's outside of scope here. But let me add a disclaimer, thanks for the tip.
